# Cannot use routes('name') function in view outside of default routes/web.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have a group that uses WEB middleware (like default), but  has its own `routes/org.php` file;

From RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{

    // Match my own domain FIRST
    Route::group(['domain' => 'a.example','www.a.example', 'admin.a.example'], function()
    {
        // Original Web Route
        Route::middleware('web')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    });



    // Match any other domains or subdomains
    Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}'], function()
    {
        // Org middleware
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/org.php'));
    });

}
```

```

in `routes/org.php` i have `Route::get('/test', 'OrgTestCtrlr@test')->name('test');`

For info:

`OrgTestCtrlr extends OrgBaseCtrlr`

.. 
`OrgBaseCtrlr extends Controller` (default laravel controller)

(So basically OrgTest extends OrgBase extending Controller)

My function for 
`public function test() { return view('org.test'); }`

calls a blade file in `../views/org/test.blade.php`

in this file i try to have a `{{ route('test') }}` reference

I get this error

> "Missing required parameters for [Route: test] [URI: test]."

*I have moved Namespaces around, tried not to extend controller so many times, etc, and i am just chasing my tail. Please advise.

Comment: Can you show the output of `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: Also note that routes in a `domain` group will get an additional parameter. If your test route is within the group, it needs to handle the domain it's being passed, i.e. `public function test($domain)`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

Comment: @ceejayoz | {domain} | GET|HEAD  | test                           | test               | App\Http\Controllers\Org\OrgBaseController@test                        | web,Closure  |
| {domain} | GET|HEAD  | view                           | view               | App\Http\Controllers\Org\OrgBaseController@view                        | web,Closure  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass domain too:

```
{{ route('test', ['domain' => 'some_domain']) }}
```

Also, change the method to:

```
public function test($domain) {
    return view('org.test');
}
```

Comment: How do i call this functionality when using a Controller@function?

Comment: @Nick just use the existing route without a modification.

Comment: So every time I want to use a route('helper') i am going to have to pass in something like `{{ route('test',['domain' => '']) }}`

Comment: any idea if there's a way to globally set the route domain for the group to avoid doing that? it seems very dirty

Comment: I just made a helper function to wrap route
so orgRoute automatically sets the domain param, done. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction)